# Subtraction doesn't work correctly with SUM

Tags: mysql

Following my query:

```
SELECT SUM(t*q) as first, 
SUM(s*q) AS second, 
SUM(t*q)-SUM(s*q) AS firstminussecond 
FROM my_table
```

Result is:

```
first = 9010.56
second = 8664 
firstminussecond = 346.5599999999995 (this should be 346.56!)
```

Why `firstminussecond` is not correct? How to solve this?

Comment: What are data types for columns `[q], [s], [t]`?

Comment: I suggest you read up on how floating point arithmetic works -- or don't use it. Your result as shown is in fact as accurate as floating point allows it to be.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point  This question, or one like it, should be on the final exam for every IT and computer science university degree program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct solution in my opinion, I changed the data types for columns `t` and `s` to `DECIMAL(10,2)` and `q` to `INT(11)`. Now `firstminussecond` is correct.

Comment: Yes, I think because of data types.

Comment: So how did data types affected calculation?

Comment: Exactly. If you don't understand floating point, don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try by this :

```
SELECT SUM(t*q) as first, 
SUM(s*q) AS second, 
FORMAT(SUM(t*q)-SUM(s*q),2) AS firstminussecond 
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(t*q) as first, 
SUM(s*q) AS second, 
cast(SUM(t*q)-SUM(s*q) as decimal(5,2)) AS firstminussecond 
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
    SELECT 
            ROUND(SUM(t*q),2) as first, 
            ROUND(SUM(s*q),2) AS second, 
            (
             ROUND(SUM(t*q),2)-
             ROUND(SUM(s*q),2)
            ) AS firstminussecond 
    FROM my_table
```

OR

```
    SELECT 
            ROUND(SUM(t*q),2) as first, 
            ROUND(SUM(s*q),2) AS second, 
            ROUND(
                    (ROUND(SUM(t*q),2)-
                     ROUND(SUM(s*q),2))
                 ,2) AS firstminussecond 
    FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ROUND` function.

```
SELECT SUM(t*q) AS first, 
SUM(s*q) AS second, 
ROUND(SUM(t*q)-SUM(s*q), 2) AS firstminussecond 
FROM my_table
```

Comment: it rounds the result `346.5599999999995` to 2 decimal places `346.56`

Comment: Adding `ROUND` makes it a different calculation. Are you saying that MySQL implements subtraction incorrectly? How can anyone may rely on it when simple subtraction a workaround?

Comment: No, we can only use the information presented to us, we have been told that `first = 9010.56`, `second = 8664`, `firstminussecond = 346.5599999999995`. From that we don't know the exact values of t, s & q. So we don't know mathematically what the exact calculation is and how BODMAS is affecting it for example. All we can do is make an educated guess that since it is coming out `.559999...` t, s or q are not integers and need to be rounded to give the desired result.

Comment: We should ask OP for additional info in order to provide educated answer. OR explicitly state assumptions in explanation of specific behavior. Calculation here is correct for `real` data type. So to change result OP needs changing data types, not manipulating the result.